# Trouble with uploading a file

Tags: php, file-upload

I can't get any files to upload successfully, it's just going to echo 'error';

HTML:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value = "2000000">
    Upload this file: <input name ="userfile" type="file">
    <input type="submit" value="Send File">
</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
if ($_FILES['userfile']['error']>0)
{
    echo 'Problem.';
    exit;
}

$upfile='/uploads/'.$_FILES['userfile']['name'];

if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['name']))
{
    if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $upfile))
    {
        echo 'Problem: could not move file';
        exit;      
    }
}
else
{
    echo 'Error';
    exit;
}

echo 'File uploaded successfully.';
?>
```

I'm sure it's something simple I'm messing up, but I've spent about an hour trying to find it. Thanks.

Comment: What does a `print_r($_FILES);` yield?

Comment: Array ( [userfile] => Array ( [name] => 005.jpg [type] => image/jpeg [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpcWyqsb [error] => 0 [size] => 332439 ) )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']))
```

`tmp_name` instead of `name`

Comment: "Problem: could not move file"

Comment: @tim but that's a new issue. Check out what `$upfile` points to and what errors you get

Comment: $upfile points to /uploads/005.jpg. I'm trying to upload a local file, would that be a problem? It's outside the web directory.

Comment: @tim - outside web directory is fine, but you need to check the path, (does directory exist, able to write so on ...)

Comment: Yeah, the directory exists and I've made sure all permissions of everything involved were set accordingly. Odd.

Comment: @tim - just to be sure, in linux, do a `ls -l /uploads/*`; does it return anything ? Or is /uploads/005.jpg exist ?

Comment: Note that /uploads/ is an absolute path from the system's root. Make sure you don't want a relative path instead.

Answer (score 1):

`$_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']` is the name of the uploaded file. `$_FILES['userfile']['name']` is just the name that the file had when it was on the computer of the user.

Answer (score 0):

For proper working, the function is_uploaded_file() needs an argument like $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], - the name of the uploaded file on the client's machine $_FILES['userfile']['name'] does not work.